# Keep Drupal content HTML in a uglified state

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

When I am adjusting content, I click on the source I want the html to be in an uglified state, so it is easier to naivagte, without having to copy and paste the html into [HTMLLint](http://jsbeautifier.org/), then into Sublime Text (at least once for editing, but definitely in ST2 if I plan on doing several iterations of edits), and then back into the RTF body area.

[image]

How do you get it to show the source in an indented view like this:

[image]

Maybe also how do you just edit the content in HTML format only?  Any Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you get it to show the source in an indented view

Well, you can't unless it is built into the Rich Text Editor module that you have installed.  [CK Editor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor), for example, does indent the HTML nicely.

> how do you just edit the content in HTML format only? Any Module?

If you want to edit the content without the Rich Text Editor, you may

1. disable that particular module `admin/config/modules`
2. or make plain text your default by going to `admin/config/content/formats` and dragging 'Plain Text' to the top of the list.